# open .bat file from angular

Tags: angular, batch-file

i would like to open a local .bat file from an angular application running on tomcat server.

i can open .bat file it if its a basic html page that runs in a browser. if the same code is integrated inside angular code, it does not open the .bat file. instead in chrome, it just opens a blank tab. ie does not do anything at all.

i tried to override the security setting in ie, but it did not help.
can you please help how to override the security setting in angular and webbrowser to get around this issue?

thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you be opening yourself up to security vulnerabilities? Format drive.... for example... But a web service may be such a method, and have it invoke your batch https://blog.art-of-coding.eu/executing-operating-system-commands-from-java/

Comment: thankyou. the link you shared does not work. and i understand the security issue around this. however this is an internal application within firewall so we are ready to go this route. do you have any suggestion on how to get this done in angular?